# Python tkinter button return filepath Python 2.7.13

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Python tkinter to get a filepath. However, I don't know how the browsefunc to do with button. Basically, I would like user to click Browse button, then the user choose the file. Then the filepath can be saved to a variable that I can use latter on. Any help would appreciate.

```
import Tkinter
import ttk
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Branch Filter')
root.geometry("598x120+250+100")
def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    return filename

ttk.Label(root,text="Select Your File (Only RAW files)").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='e')
bButton = ttk.Button(root, text ="Browse", command=browsefunc).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
print bButton
```

Comment: You can't usefully return anything from a button's command, as the function isn't being called by your code.  You need to do whatever it is you want to do with the selected filename from within `browsefunc()`.  If you truly don't want to do anything with the filename at that moment in time, store it somewhere you can access it later - a global variable, perhaps.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks! can you explain to me what can I do to execute the browsefunc? I thought when user click the button, it triggers the command within that button...

Comment: That should be exactly what happens - are you not getting the file dialog when you click the button?  It's just the `return` in the function that's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
def browsefunc():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return filename
```

with:

```
filename = ''
def browsefunc():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

When a method can't return.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is saving the file name to a local variable and binding the function to a button. If you want to use that variable you can make a global variable where you can save the path whenever you choose a new one.